# how to add incremental number to specific column in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
  code      tank      length      dia       diff
  123       3         625         210       -0.38
  123       5         635         210       1.2
```

I want to add 1 only in length for 5 times if the diff is positive and subtract 1 if the dip is negative. My desired dataframe looks like

```
 code      tank      length       diameter
  123       3         625         210
  123       3         624         210
  123       3         623         210
  123       3         622         210
  123       3         621         210
  123       3         620         210
  123       5         635         210
  123       5         636         210
  123       5         637         210
  123       5         638         210
  123       5         639         210
  123       5         640         210
```

I am doing following in pandas.

```
  df.add(1)
```

But, its adding 1 to all the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) 6 times, then add counter values by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and last create default `RangeIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(6)].copy()
df1['length'] += df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or:

```
df1 = (df.loc[df.index.repeat(6)]
         .assign(length = lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + x['length'])
         .reset_index(drop=True))

print (df1)
    code  tank  length  dia
0    123     3     625  210
1    123     3     626  210
2    123     3     627  210
3    123     3     628  210
4    123     3     629  210
5    123     3     630  210
6    123     5     635  210
7    123     5     636  210
8    123     5     637  210
9    123     5     638  210
10   123     5     639  210
11   123     5     640  210
```

EDIT:

```
df1 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(6)].copy()
add = df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount()

mask = df1['diff'] < 0
df1['length'] = np.where(mask, df1['length'] - add, df1['length'] + add)
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)

print (df1)
    code  tank  length  dia  diff
0    123     3     625  210 -0.38
1    123     3     624  210 -0.38
2    123     3     623  210 -0.38
3    123     3     622  210 -0.38
4    123     3     621  210 -0.38
5    123     3     620  210 -0.38
6    123     5     635  210  1.20
7    123     5     636  210  1.20
8    123     5     637  210  1.20
9    123     5     638  210  1.20
10   123     5     639  210  1.20
11   123     5     640  210  1.20
```

Comment: What if I want to subtract instead of add? What change I have to make?

Comment: @Neil - It depends what need, I think `df1['length'] -= df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount()` or maybe `df1['length'] -= df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount(ascending=False)`

Comment: Can we add or subtract basis some condition? e.g. in `tank_no` 3, I want to add 5 and in `tank_no` 5, I want to subtract 5.

Comment: @Neil - Most general is use dictionary like `d= {3:5, 5:-5}` and then new column with `df['new'] = df[''tank].map(d)`

Comment: @Neil - What column is subtracted?

Comment: 1 is added and subtracted in length depending upon positive and negative values of `diff` column

Comment: @Neil - Is possible add expcted output from sample data? Because there is added `diff` column, but in output data was not changed. thank you.

Comment: I have already changed the output data. If you see for `tank_no` 3 since the diff column has negative value, length is decreasing by 1 till 620.

Comment: @Neil - oops, mea culpa, I miss it.

Comment: @Neil - Answe was edited by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) - subtracted and added values

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pd.concat`, `np.cumsum` and `groupby` + `.add`.

If you want to substract, simply multiply `addition * -1` so for example: `(np.cumsum(np.ones(n))-1) * -1`

```
n = 6

new = pd.concat([df]*n).sort_values(['code', 'length']).reset_index(drop=True)
addition = np.cumsum(np.ones(n))-1
new['length'] = new.groupby(['code', 'tank'])['length'].apply(lambda x: x.add(addition))
```

**Output**

```
    code  tank  length  dia
0    123     3   625.0  210
1    123     3   626.0  210
2    123     3   627.0  210
3    123     3   628.0  210
4    123     3   629.0  210
5    123     3   630.0  210
6    123     5   635.0  210
7    123     5   636.0  210
8    123     5   637.0  210
9    123     5   638.0  210
10   123     5   639.0  210
11   123     5   640.0  210
```